# as3 accessing CHILD in External loaded swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

How do I get to the MovieClips within an externally loaded Movie Clip.

Lets say I have a movie Called ONE in the swf I just loaded. How can I work with it alpha, position and other properties of the children of this clip?

```
CODE IN MAIN TIMLINE: 

    var LoadedMC:Loader = new Loader();
    LoadedMC.load(new URLRequest("amplitude.swf"));

    LoadedMC.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, bL);
    function bL (e:Event):void{
    addChild(LoadedMC);
}
```

Now its loaded I want to change the postino of the clip called ONE in the movie LoadedMC I just created.

Thanks for your help.
-Ed

Comment: ToddBFisher = spiderman of as3!

Comment: wow so many posts from you on accessing children in external swf - each sounding more desperate lol

Comment: Yes, MikeW, I was pretty desperate and spent many many hours on it. Thankfully these forms helps a ton and ... now I know the rest of the story. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think you would do something like:

```
//Cast the content into a movie clip
var someMC:MovieClip = MovieClip(LoadedMC.content);
//or try
var someMC:MovieClip = LoadedMC.content as MovieClip;

//then access the child
someMC.ONE.x = 50;
someMC.ONE.y = 100;
```

Comment: DUDE YOU ARE THE SPIDERMAN OF As3!  Thank you sooooo much!

it also works for Children of Children! someMC.ONE.TWO.x = 50;